# unresolved external symbol, but I included files with the function definitions?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I'm writing a C++ console app to test an API.  I added the `...\SDK\include\` folder path under "Additional Include Directories."  Here's the code for my main .cpp file:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "aaapi.h"
#include "aaapidef.h"
#include "aaapiver.h"
#include "aaatypes.h"
#include "aadmsapi.h"
#include "aadmsdef.h"

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    LPCWSTR dbName=L"xyz.com:abc";
    LPCWSTR user=L"";
    LPCWSTR pwd=L"";
    LPCWSTR schema=L"";
    bool resultInit=aaApi_Initialize(AAMODULE_ALL);
    bool resultLogin=aaApi_Login(AAAPIDB_UNKNOWN,dbName,user,pwd,schema);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting these errors:

```
unresolved external symbol _aaApi_Initialize@4 referenced in function _wmain
unresolved external symbol _aaApi_Login@20 referenced in function _wmain
```

From the errors, it seems like both of the API functions are undefined, but I thought the `#include` statements would have taken care of that, especially because their function headers show up in the Intellisense.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

The #include statements are for the compiler. The message is from the linker. You have to tell it where the corresponding .obj files are.

Comment: The SDK folder and subfolders don't have any .obj files.  There are a bunch of DLLs; would those have what I'm looking for?  I ran a `dumpbin` on the DLLs but didn't find any reference to .obj files.

Comment: You need to specify the .lib files required.

Comment: Ok, I just added the .lib files under Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies.  But now I'm suddenly getting `error LNK1104: cannot open file 'dmkernel32.lib'`, and it persists when I remove the .lib files I just added.  What did I do wrong?

Comment: You need to provide their locations. Isn't there another argument for that? Don't be discouraged, you're making progress here.